# Get a list of associations from :accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get a list of the associations that a model `:accepts_nested_attributes_for`. For instance, I'd like to get `[:children, :other_children]` from this model:

```
class ParentResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  has_many :other_children
  has_many :non_nested_children

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, :other_children
end
```

Right now, I'm doing this with the following function:

```
def self.nested_associations
  reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name).select do |association_name|
    association_name if method_defined?("#{association_name}_attributes=".to_sym)
  end
end
```

I get the feeling that there's a baked-in way to get this array, however. If so, what's the proper method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the 'correct way', but can't you just do:

```
ParentResource.nested_attributes_options.keys
```

Comment: Far more elegant than my solution. Thanks!